# Fatal error: No such file or directory for header file

Tags: c, file, makefile, header, ncurses

I'm currently running Ubuntu (The latest firmware) and have a bunch of directories I've made for my c-programming. However, I’m getting an error when compiling telling me that it can't find the "file.h" header file
Within my main folder "temp"
the directories are as follows

```
temp
```

Then:

```
src bin include assets Makefile
```

src contains a .c file which is:

```
#include "file.h"

int main(void)
{
    initscr();
    noecho();
    cbreak();

    char ch;
    FILE * ptr;
    ptr = fopen("input.txt","r");

    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        mvprintw(0,0,"Error reading from file");
        exit(1);
    }

    while( ( ch = fgetc(ptr) ) != EOF )
    mvprintw(0,0,"%c",ch);
    refresh();

    fclose(ptr);
    return 0;
```

}

and my include folder contains the Header file(which gives me the error)
This is what file.h contains...

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <ncurses.h>
```

I've also got a makefile as follows:

```
all:
        gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 src/file.c assets/input.txt -o bin/runMe
```

And finally assets include a .txt file "input.txt" which the program is just supposed  to read some characters from the text file, which is in the assets directory. I've tried using the "#include <  >" notation, but that didn't seem to help. I also tried to use something along the lines of "#include "include/file.h", but as well it was to no avail.

Comment: `-I path/to/your/include/folder` before any of the source files in your compiler may help.

Comment: I've changed it to : gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 -Iinclude/include src/file.c assets/input.txt -o bin/runMe -lncurses

Comment: But I still  get the same error

Comment: Why did you add two include directories, `include/include`?  It seems like you want just `-Iinclude`, based on your directory structure.  You should use the `#include "file.h"` syntax, not `#include <file.h>`.

Answer (score 4):

If `file.h` is in `temp` directory, add to your command in the `Makefile`:

```
-Itemp
```

And in `a.c`:

```
#include <file.h>
```

You should use `#include "file.h"` when `file.h` is in the same directory of the file that include it.